# Laravel How can I return array of objects

Tags: php, laravel

I've got simple array of objects:

```
"myObject" => [
   'key1' => ["property1" => 'value1', "property2" => 'value2'],
   'key2' => ["property1" => 'value1', "property2" => 'value2'],
   ...
],
```

When I'm returning this via laravel dot syntax:

```
return [
   'listOfObjects' => trans(objects)
]
```

I've got:

```
myObject: {
   key1: {property1:'value1', property2:'value2'},
   key2: {property1:'value1', property2:'value2'},
etc..
}
```

It's simple.

Now how can I modify my return to get only an array of objects, without numbers:

```
myObject: {
   {property1:'value1', property2:'value2'},
   {property1:'value1', property2:'value2'},
etc..
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the indices?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I don't need them in the frontend

Comment: Why should you just echo the array as it is? You have some sort of looping through the array and building a fontend structure arround it hopefully. Upon that you can decide yourself what properties or indices you want to print and which not. If you echo the array because your users are developers, they will understand what the indices are there for.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer sure, I can loop, but I hoped to find the solution on return stage

Comment: Why not just when you foreach or whatever use $object as $key => $values and just use the $values not the keys?

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
I think I now understand what you want. What you call an Array in PHP is not necessarily an Array in JSON. For JSON your "myObject" is an Object.
For JSON to recognize something as an Array, it can only have numbers as keys.

So change the keys from "key1", "key2", ... into 0, 1, ...

```
$result = [];
foreach($myObject as $element){
  $result[] = $element;
}
return $result;
```

After that, $result looks like this

```
$result = [
  0 => ["prop1" => "val1", "prop2" => "val2"],
  1 => ["prop1" => "val1", "prop2" => "val2"]
]
```

Or equivalently in the short notation

```
$result = [
  ["prop1" => "val1", "prop2" => "val2"],
  ["prop1" => "val1", "prop2" => "val2"]
]
```

Now JSON should recognize this as an Array instead of an Object when Laravel converts $result to JSON or you make it yourself: `return response()->json($result);`

[previous:]
You can not return an object which has values but no keys.
The simplest form of keys are numbers, which is what arrays are using.

Comment: it could be an array of objects, you don't need any keys then

Comment: Think about it: If there would be a way to send an object like { {prop1:val1}, {prop2:val2} }, how would you head for the second object, {prop2:val2} ?

Comment: I agree with that, and that's what I want to get, but this is not the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to solve in PHP. As it is said in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

> "...index may be of type string or integer. When index is omitted, an
>   integer index is automatically generated, starting at 0..."

Also, what you are asking seems to be quite pointless. If you could describe what it is you are trying to accomplish, people might be able to help you better.

Comment: you might be right, I just want to get rid of `'key1' => ` and get array of objects without those `'key1' => ` indexes

Comment: I can only say what @Baron von Squirrel commented under his answer: how would you get any content of that array? Loops are using indexes of arrays, you wouldn't even be able to loop through an "array" like that. To be accurate, that thing wouldn't even be an array, as arrays are defined by key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The function to use in this case is:

```
$tryit = trans('objects');
$new = collect($tryit)->flatten(1);
$new->values()->all();
```

unfortunatelly there is a bug in Laravel 5.6 on this function and it digs two level deep instead of one :/